# Jquery math less than 0 show 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

how would i stop the below returning a value less than 0. I want anything less than 0 to show as 0. Any help appreciated.

```
$("#spanrPower_CO2").text (Math.round(-data[0] * 16.8) * 100 / 100);
```

Comment: `Math.max(0, Math.round(-data[0] * 16.8) * 100 / 100);`

Comment: You will probably get your intended result with clearer code as `Math.max(0, -data[0] * 16.8).toFixed(2)`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-in-javascript

Comment: @LutzL: nicer than my answer methinks. Do consider promoting it.

Comment: Use an extra line of code or two, and make it crystal clear: `if ( value < 0 ) { value = 0; }`.

Comment: this worked great thanks!

(Math.max(0, -data[0] * 16.8).toFixed(0));

Answer (score 2):

`data[0] > 0 ? 0 : -Math.round(16.8 * data[0]);` is probably clearer.

Note that unless you're approaching floating point infinity, `* 100 / 100` is a no-op.

Answer (score 0):

```
(Math.max(0, -data[0] * 16.8).toFixed(0));
```